# ssh-agent running in x86 mode, not Apple Silicon, on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: homebrew, ssh, apple-silicon, zsh

On my M1 MacBook, I'm trying to migrate as many apps and CLI utilities as I can from running the x86-based binaries to running the universal or ARM-based binaries for Apple Silicon.

I noticed that `ssh-agent` is running as `kind: Intel`:

[image]

This is the binary being run:

```
❯ which zsh
/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh


❯ which ssh-agent
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
```

it seems the `ssh-agent` installed to `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` is not Apple Silicon? How do I switch over to an M1-optimized version?

Comment: Are you running terminal in Rosetta? `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` is a universal binary on my machine.

Comment: *Is* that the `zsh` that's actually running?  Why did you feel the need to replace the system-provided zsh?